# How can you chain supertest requests when one is dependent on the other?

Tags: node.js, express, testing, supertest

So right now the output is:

```
Warning: superagent request was sent twice, because both .end() and .then() were called. Never call .end() if you use promises
Warning: .end() was called twice. This is not supported in superagent
GET /api/things 200 3.009 ms - 2414
superagent: double callback bug
WARNING
```

The thing is, I need the `res` object that I get back from calling `.end()` in order to test the ETag functionality. It never goes into the second `.end()` and doesn't print out that console log.

The innermost `.catch(done)` is the one that's being called.

```
it('should return things', done => {
  const promises = [];

  promises.push(Thing.create(testThing));
  promises.push(Thing.create(testThing));

  Promise.all(promises)
    .then(things => {
      request(app)
        .get('/api/things')
        .expect(200)
        .end((err, res) => {
          const etag = res.get('ETag')
          if (err)
            return done(err);
          request(app)
            .get('/api/things')
            .set('If-None-Match', etag)
            .expect(304)
            .end((err, res) => {
              console.log('are we able to make it back here?');
              expect(err).to.not.exist;
              expect(res.body.data).to.be.undefined;
              expect(res.get('ETag')).to.be.equal(etag);
              return done(err);
            })
        })
        .catch(done);
    })
    .catch(done);
});
});
```

Does anyone have any ideas on why this might be happening, and how to go about testing such a thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, I was doing the following:

```
if (req.header('If-None-Match') === allThingsEtag) {
    // dont send allThings
    res.status(304);
}
```

I needed to actually set the body of the response so it knew to return it, like so:

```
if (req.header('If-None-Match') === allThingsEtag) {
    // dont send allThings
    res.status(304);
    res.json();
}
```

I know this is incredibly specific to my case, but in the off chance that anyone runs into this as well, that's the solution I had to come up with. So maybe check your api code.

In order to get around the `.end()` being called twice problem, I changed my tests to use `.then()`.

Comment: I know you already solved this, but you could have also used the `sendStatus` function if you didn't explicitly need a json response and content-type.

`res.sendStatus(304);`

Answer (score 7):

Wasted 1 hour on this.

Official documentation is not very good:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest

Below worked correctly:

```
let request = require("supertest");
var assert = require("assert");
// const chai = require("chai");                     // can be chai instead of assert

describe("Run tests", () => {
  request = request("http://localhost:3001");        // must be here

  it("get", async () => {

    request
      .get("/")
      .expect("Content-Type", /json/)
      .expect(200)
      .then((response) => {                          // must be then, not a callback
        assert(response.body.data !== undefined);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        assert(err === undefined);
      });

  });

});
```